# Redirect if user not logged in

Tags: php, html

i link below the PHP part for control and redirect the user when clicking on a link.

```
session_start();
        if($_SESSION['LoggedIn']==TRUE)
        {
            //DO SOMETHING
        }
        else
        {
        header("e.g. REDIRECT TO THE PAGE IN LOCALHOST ");
        }
```

This is my html page / nav link

```
<a class="dropdown-link" href="account.php">Il mio account</a>
<a class="dropdown-link" href="orders.php">I miei ordini</a>
```

is that possible to redirect the user in different page using the same file?

Comment: I assume you're asking about [require](http://php.net/require)/[include](http://php.net/include)?

Comment: yes but I need to change the page for the redirect when clicking the links

Comment: Can not get question properly. can you elaborate it?

Comment: i have 2 links 1 for the order and 1 for the account detail.
I need to redirect the user if he is not logged in in the login page but  after the authentication, the file need to redirect him to the page chosen early.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a file with name like `authenticate.php` and include it in all pages where logged-in is required, it contains following code:

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['LoggedIn']==TRUE)
{
  //DO SOMETHING
}
else
{
  header("location: index.php");
}
```

If user is not logged-in, then user will be redirected to `index.php`

Comment: yes, include this script/code in both *account.php* and *orders.php*...

Answer (score 0):

Try the folowing code. It must work in your case.Just changed the php file names:

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['LoggedIN']))
{
   header("location:home.php");
}
else
{
     header("location: login");
}
```